# Using the displaymath shorthand \[ \] for equation or align instead

Tags: equations

I want to be able to use the `\[ ... \]` shorthand to enter either the `equation` or `align` environment instead of the `displaymath` environment. Is it possible to do this? I know you can define new commands, but I'm not sure if it is a problem if they are already defined.

Context: I use MultiMarkDown and you use `\\[` and `\\]` to enter math using raw LaTeX. It works fine, except that the math environment you are entering is `displaymath` instead of `equation` or `align`.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what syntax you want. If you want to change `\[` and `\]`, just use something like:

```
\renewcommand\[{\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand\]{\end{equation}}
```

---

If you want to use commands `\\[` and `\\]` with double backslash, things may be more complex. It is possible, but difficult to implemented, and not recommended, since there is already a `\\` command and usage `\\[2ex]`.