# Use displaymath shorthand \[ \] for align and other amsmath environments

Tags: amsmath, align

This question is closely related to this one: [Using the displaymath shorthand \[ \] for equation or align instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21148/using-the-displaymath-shorthand-for-equation-or-align-instead).  I use Multimarkdown (MMD) to generate my LaTeX documents.  MMD uses the escape character set `\\[` and `\\]` to create displaymath shorthand `\[` and `\]` in LaTeX.  I'd like to re-assign `\[` and `\]` to `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`.  The previous question had a solution for other environments (e.g., `equation`), but I would like to use the `align` environment.  According to the amsmath technical notes, it's impossible to create abbreviations for its math environments.  Does anyone know a work-around?  I have tried

```
\renewenvironment{displaymath}{\align}{\endalign}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Noam, welcome to TeX.sx. I've formatted the link to the other question: You can just insert the full link in your question, it will automatically be formatted to use the question title as the link text. No need for URL shorteners. Also, I've formatted your code snippets by enclosing them in backticks (you could also just select them and press the `{}` key), and I've removed the "Thanks!", because that's just the custom here `=)`

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's impossible. However, you can do `\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`. A better route may be to configure MMD to directly produce the `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`, if that's possible.

Comment: `\renewenvironment{displaymath}{\align}{\endalign}` does work for me. Did you load `amsmath`? Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2674).

Comment: Note that using `align*` unconditionally is not necessarily a good idea, refer to [amsmath - align vs equation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321/align-vs-equation). The question [Define a single environnement for equation and align - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681687/define-a-single-environnement-for-equation-and-align?noredirect=1#comment1691480_681687) has a workaround.

Answer (score 9):

You can use TeX's `\def` command for redefining `\[...\]`:

```
\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\begin{document}
\[
   ax + b &= 0 \\
   ab &= 1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: align redefinition test output]