# Define a single environment for equation and align

Tags: equations, align

I would like to define a single command like "\[...\]" for **equation** and **align** environment.
I could always use align, but it seems that vertical spaces are different and a bit too big for a single equation.

My question is then to define a default environment **equation**, that moves to **align** when **&** is used.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! This is indeed what @user202729 says. Can we define an environment that checks if there is **&** in the text and then chose **\begin{align*} … \end{align*}** or **\begin{equation*} … \end{equation*}** in order to always have the « good » vertical alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymath*}{b}{
  \tl_if_in:nnTF {#1} {&} {
    \begin{align*} #1 \end{align*}
  } {
    \begin{equation*} #1 \end{equation*}
  }
}{
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}



\begin{mymath*}
  1 = 2
\end{mymath*}

\begin{mymath*}
  1 &= 2
\end{mymath*}

\begin{equation*}
  \verb|123|
\end{equation*}

% cases where the new environment fail

%\def\tabmark{&}
%\begin{mymath*}
%  1 \tabmark = 2
%\end{mymath*}

%\begin{mymath*}
%  \verb|123|
%\end{mymath*}

\end{document}
```

Self-explanatory.

The drawbacks are obvious, refer to the last 2 commented-out blocks. (as well as losing synctex in `equation*` environment)

There's also another case where `align*` is picked instead of `equation*` when there's a nested environment inside e.g. `split`
`aligned` that use `&` or similar -- which you can solve by using some even more sophisticated parser, but that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is exactly what I was looking for. Just add `\def\[#1\]{\begin{mymath} #1 \end{mymath}}` after the definition of your environnement.

Comment: A bit more challenge ? What if we want this environnement to turn into `alignat` when a number is giving in argument ? Or maybe counting the numer of `&`, but it might make compilation longer.