# One command/environment for both equation and equation*

Tags: macros

I want to define a new command/environment for both `equation` and `equation*`, based on whether the content contains `\label`.
For the following equation,

```latex
\begin{mymath}
f = g
\end{mymath}
```

environment `mymath` will be substituted with `equation*`; but for the following,

```latex
\begin{mymath}
\label{eq:test}
f = g
\end{mymath}
```

environment `equation` will be used instead.

I saw this post [a single environment for equation and align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681687/define-a-single-environment-for-equation-and-align) and tried using `\tl_if_in:nnTF {#1} {\label} {}{}`, which didn't work.

Comment: Is it permissible to assume that the `\begin{equation[*]}`, `\label{...}`, and `\end{equation[*]}` directives, and the display-math expression, will always be on lines all by themselves? Or could they all be one line? Please advise.

Comment: Hi @Mico, if this makes the construction more straightforward, then one can assume they are on separate lines.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use e.g `showonlyrefs` from the `mathtools` package, or the `autonum` package?

Comment: Hi @campa, for `showonlyrefs`, I think you need to label all equations. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, equations without label aren't shown.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @campa! It indeed works; I guess I used the wrong option other than `showonlyrefs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a good way to go, but you're the judge.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymath}{b}
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \label }
   {
    \begin{equation} #1 \end{equation}
   }
   {
    \begin{equation*} #1 \end{equation*}
   }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This one is not numbered
\begin{mymath}
f = g
\end{mymath}
but this one is
\begin{mymath}
\label{eq:test}
f = g
\end{mymath}
and let's check that the line below starts at the left margin.

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works like a charm. May I ask why do you think this is not a good way?

Comment: @atlas Because it's easier to add or remove `*` than trusting in the presence or not of `\label`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution (similar to egreg's but uses a command instead of an environment). It takes the label as an optional argument and uses * or not accordingly:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myeq}{o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
            \begin{equation*}
                        #2
            \end{equation*}
    }
    {%
            \begin{equation}
                        #2
                        \label{#1}
            \end{equation}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\myeq{F = ma}

\myeq[newtons_law]{F = \frac{dp}{dt}}

See eq. \ref{newtons_law}

\end{document}
```